# Upgrading Microsoft.Practices.Prism to a Nuget package

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, prism, nuget-package, .net-standard-2.0

I need to upgrade lots of projects in old app source. The application uses WPF nad many projects reference Prism v4.0.0 and specifically the `Microsoft.Practices.Prism.dll` assembly. I'm trying to find a replacement for it from the official Nuget repository but can't find anything. There is no Nuget package with that library and all the newer packages are not backwards compatible with the old code.

Is there a way to replace the `Microsoft.Practices.Prism` assembly with an official, newer Nuget package?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to replace the `Microsoft.Practices.Prism` assembly with an official, newer Nuget package?

[Yes](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Wpf/), but not without you changing your code.